# Routed page won't render if callback contains process.exit

Tags: node.js, process

I'm trying to render a page on a web browser and then exit the Node.js express webserver that served up the page. The code I'm using in the function that is called to do this is:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/restart', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('resetTimer', {}, function() {
        console.log("Render resetTimer page and exit.");
        process.exit(); // kill Express webserver
      });
    });
```

However, I'm getting

```
 This site can’t be reached

 localhost refused to connect.
```

in the web browser, which suggests that the exit is happening before the web page is rendered, even though the exit command is in a callback. If I comment out the process.exit command I see the console log message, but if I don't comment it out, the page isn't rendered and the log message isn't output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  And, do you realize that a web page usually has other resources (images, scripts, fonts, style sheets, etc...) that need to be fetched from the same server?  Did you try exiting on a `setTimeout()` and you can experiment with the amount of delay needed in order to make sure the page has been fully sent to the client.

Comment: I need to restart the express webserver in a quick and dirty fashion. In the shell it's run with a bash script that restarts it. That part works (and 5 seconds later the web browser loads the page due to repeated attempts). But I don't understand why the render process is calling the callback before it's completed rendering the page. This seems wrong to me.

Comment: `res.render()` calls its callback when the data has been given to TCP (likely with `socket.write()`.  It doesn't know when exactly TCP finishes delivering it to the client and thus doesn't wait for that.  A safer way to do this would be to render the page and not restart until an ajax call from that page is received.  They you know the page has been loaded into the browser.  You could even safely wait for other page resources to be loaded before making the ajax call.

Comment: Well, actually, it probably calls the callback when data has been given to the response stream which has a buffer on top of the socket.  You could monitor stream events if you want to know when the stream closes.

Comment: That's an idea. Have an ajax call from resetTimer page trigger the process.exit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `res.render()` callback is called when the page has been handed off to the response stream, even though it may not yet have been fully delivered to the client.  So, if you kill the process at that point, the client delivery may not complete.

I can think of two ways to work around this:

1. Create a listener for the close event on the response stream and when you get that event, you will know that everything has been sent and you can shut down your server.  This will not allow for any other page resources that might need to be loaded (images, style sheets, fonts, etc...) since they may be requested after the page had loaded.
2. Put an ajax call in the page itself so that AFTER the page loads, it makes the ajax call and then you don't actually restart your server until you get the ajax call.  If you don't make the Ajax call until the window `load` event, then you could also make sure that all other page resources were loaded before rebooting the server.

Note that either of these options allow all sorts of DOS attacks on your server (causing it to reboot whenever an attacker wants).